# Fastest way to filter list of dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have a list of dicts `inserts` that should be inserted into the database. Since some elements are already in the db `db_entry_ids`, I want to filter them out. Right now the code is pretty simple:

```
[d for d in inserts if d["entry_id"] not in db_entry_ids]
```

with

```
len(inserts) = 35000  
len(db_entry_ids) =280000
```

Python needs few minutes for that. I hope there is some simple way to make that more efficient.

PS: `d["entry_id"]` is a string, as well as `db_entry_ids`, is a list of strings. So **`id`** might be a bit misleading.

Comment: What is `type(db_entry_ids)`?

Comment: Good question. They should be both list of strings. Guess Ids was a bit misleading

Comment: if `db_entry_ids` is a list, make it a set. Lookup in a list is O(n), in a set is O(1). [See](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: Are the `d['entry_id']`s unique? Should `db_entry_ids` be modified after an insert? I suppose converting `db_entry_ids` to a set and putting those inserts into a transaction would speed the whole process up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys :) yes that solve the question!

Comment: @MichaelRazum, No problem. I've marked this as a duplicate of Q&A which adds some more explanation / colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `db_entry_ids` to a set. The `not in` operation in sets is way faster.

```
db_entry_ids = set(db_entry_ids)
[d for d in inserts if d["entry_id"] not in db_entry_ids]
```

See this for reference: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: performance improved from few minutes to few seconds :)

Comment: Note : you might want to add `d['entry_id']` to `db_entry_ids` in order to avoid duplicates .